# LEFT JOIN query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I'm trying to make select query in Postgres using LEFT JOIN but I can't get proper results. I have 2 tables - `offers` and `images` and when offers have images, they are inserted in table images. But not all offers have images.

Now, I want to select all offers (both with images and without images) from what is searched and if these offers have images, to show them. I tried using LEFT JOIN to select from `images` if there are images, but when I'm trying to display them, there are NULL values - without any returned values.

What's wrong with my query?

```
$sql->query("SELECT count(offers.id) as offers_count FROM offers LEFT JOIN images ON images.offer_id = offers.id AND images.file_type = 3 WHERE $where"); //$where is what is searched from user


$SQL = "SELECT  images.filename, * FROM offers LEFT JOIN images ON images.offer_id = offers.id AND images.file_type = 3 WHERE  $where $result LIMIT 12 OFFSET ".($page-1)*12);

for ($i=0; $i<$sql->getNumRows(); $i++) {
$obj = $sql->getRow($i);
offers::show_offer($obj); 
}

function show_offer($offer_obj) {
$img = $offer_obj['filename']; 
$picture = '<img src="/'.$img.'"  />';
echo '<div>';
echo $picture; 
//some other info I show
echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: I ran it into Postgre Client, but I can't find where problem is.When there is no image, it is NULL, but instead not showing this image, whole info for this offer is not shown and even no id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `select table1.col1, *` [works in Postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d07c7/1/0).  I believe it is an error Oracle, did you mean that?

Comment: If you don't get an error, but an empty result you need to show us the **real** query you are executing, not the PHP(?) code. If you don't get an empty result but a wrong one, **edit** your question add some sample data (ideally as `insert into`) statements and the result you get (as _formatted_ text) including the **real** statement that is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't work because of this condition in the WHERE clause:

```
images.file_type = 3
```

For rows that don't match at the right side of the LEFT JOIN, the SQL engine will put NULL into all columns corresponding to the right side table. Then, the condition `images.file_type = 3` is evaluated to false, as `images.file_type` is NULL. So the rows without image are eliminated.

In effect, this condition cancels the effect of the LEFT JOIN, making it the equivalent of an INNER JOIN (the same as JOIN alone)

You may solve this by applying the restriction on `file_type` before the LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT i.somecolumn, offers.* FROM
    offers
 LEFT JOIN
   (select * from images WHERE file_type=3) AS i
 ON i.offer_id = offers.id 
 WHERE  $where ...
```

Make sure that the other clauses in  `$where` are also not  conditions ON images.* columns, or they must be processed similarly.